# How to get the first non-empty value amongst 4 dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 date values that has a descending order of importance for a list of 200k+ lines.
The order of importance is date1 > date2 > date3 > date4. Sometimes, there will be no values or a single space string in the date values. If that occurs, I will then need to move on to the next most important date. date4 will always be a proper date value.

I have a simple function below that returns the desired values but I was wondering if there are any ways to make it faster? My list could easily balloon up to 500K+ lines and would take up substantial time

```
Function getConEndDate(date1 As Date, date2 As Date, date3 As Date, date4 As Date) As Date
Dim endDate As Date

If Len(date1) > 2 Then
    endDate = date1
ElseIf Len(date2) > 2 Then
    endDate = date2
ElseIf Len(date3) > 2 Then
    endDate = date3
Else
    endDate = date4 + 30
End If

getConEndDate = endDate
End Function
```

Comment: There is something fundimentally wrong here:  Your function accepts parameters of type `Date`.  `Len(AnyDate)` will _always_ be > 2.  If you pass and empty cell, it will be converted to "00:00:00", if you pass a single space string, it will runtime error.  Also, the function itself is fast (calling it 1,000,000 times with valid dates runs in < 0.2 seconds on my hardware).  Your problem is certainly elsewhere, probably looping a 500,000 row range (which is easily solved): show us your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading dates from a range, you may try something like this...

```
Function getConEndDate(rng As Range) As Date
Dim endDate         As Date
Dim i               As Long
Dim endDateFound    As Boolean

For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count - 1
    If IsDate(rng.Cells(i).Value) Then
        endDate = rng.Cells(i).Value
        endDateFound = True
    End If
Next i
If endDateFound Then
    getConEndDate = endDate
Else
    getConEndDate = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count) + 30
End If

End Function
```

Then if your dates are in the range A2:A5000, you may use it like this...

```
=getConEndDate(A2:A5000)
```

This function assumes that the last cell in the range is always a date as you stated in the description otherwise you may check the last cell as well to see if it's a date and then add 30 to it if no prior date was found in the range provided.

**Updated Code:**

```
Function getConEndDate(rng As Range) As Date
Dim endDate         As Date
Dim arr             As Variant
Dim i               As Long
Dim endDateFound    As Boolean

arr = rng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
    If IsDate(arr(i, 1)) Then
        endDate = arr(i, 1)
        endDateFound = True
    End If
Next i
If endDateFound Then
    getConEndDate = endDate
Else
    getConEndDate = arr(UBound(arr, 1), 1) + 30
End If

End Function
```

Comment: If the OP has worries about performance, then first reading the range into an array would be faster.  Also you can `Exit For` from the loop as soon as you get a date.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you.